# Saving patchwork ggplots with furrr future map only saves one of the plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork, furrr

I am trying to save a list of patchworked ggplots (ie ggplots that have been wrapped together into 1 plot using the package `patchwork`).

My real data is creating several hundred plots so I would like to use `furrr` to speed it up. Using `furrr::future_map` works totally fine to save a standard ggplot however when I run it on a `patchwork` plot it is only saving one of the plots. See below with some default ggplots in place of my actual long list of plots.

The plot that is save by the `furrr::map` always seems to be the last plot (bottom right) in the patchwork plot.

Does anyone know why `future_imap` and `imap` are behaving differently here and it there is anything that can be done?

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(purrr)
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future
plan(multisession, workers =  availableCores() - 1)

#make some example plots
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg))
p1 <- p + geom_point()
p2 <- p + geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))
p3 <- p + geom_point(aes(shape = factor(cyl)))
p4 <- p + geom_point(aes(size = qsec))

#make some example patchwork plots
allplots <- patchwork::wrap_plots(p1,p2,p3,p4)
allplots2 <- patchwork::wrap_plots(p1,p3,p2,p4)
allplots3 <- patchwork::wrap_plots(p3,p1,p2,p4)
allplots4 <- patchwork::wrap_plots(p4,p1,p2,p1)

#save list of standard ggplots to confirm future can output normal plots as expected
# These all look basically the same except small differences in resolution (not setting so not worried about this)
list_of_plots <- list("one"=p1,"two"=p2,"three"=p3,"four"=p4)
plots_save_imap <- imap(list_of_plots, ~ggsave(file.path("C:/temp/test",paste0(.y, ".png")), plot = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
plots_save_futureimap <- future_imap(list_of_plots, ~ggsave(file.path("C:/temp/test",paste0(.y, "future.png")), plot = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
# all look fine

#save list of patchworks

list_of_allplots <- list("first"= allplots,"second"= allplots2,"third"= allplots3,"fourth"= allplots4)

plots_save_imapPW <- imap(list_of_allplots, ~ggsave(file.path("C:/temp/test",paste0(.y, ".png")), plot = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
#> Saving 7 x 5 in image
```

Example: Plot looks as expected with all 4 subplots

[image: Plot looks as expected with all 4 subplots]

```
plots_save_futureimapPW <- future_imap(list_of_allplots, ~ggsave(file.path("C:/temp/test",paste0(.y, "future1.png")), plot = .x))
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
#> Saving 7 x 7 in image
```

Example: only one of the plots is output to each file (
[image: Only one of the plots saves]

If I just run

```
plots_futureimapPW <- future_imap(list_of_allplots, ~print(.x))
plots_futureimapPW
```

then `plots_futureimapPW` does give me the full patchworks within RStudio

<sup>Created on 2022-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I've reproduced this on my machine, and it's indeed spooky behavior. Instead of saving `list_of_allplots[[i]]`, `ggsave` saves `list_of_allplots[[i]][[1]]` How much longer would it take to just write them without `{future}`? Alternatively, you may look into `doParallel()` and rewrite the functional programming as a loop.

Comment: Yeah its probably one of those things where I was looking for the easy win as my script was already using imap and I just threw a future on the front and probably not going to spend the time changing to `doParallel` as I have no experience with it. So mostly I was hoping it might have a known workaround